# Kubernetes installation starting forever

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm using microservices architecture in the backend (node js), i created images for all of them with docker and now i need kubernetes to run all of the services together.
when i want to install kuberbetes from docker desktop, its starting forever.
I tried several solutions but none of them worked. my system operation is Windows 10 Enterprise.

**I deleted config file in** `C:\Users\<user name>\.kube\config`.

**I deleted pki folder in** `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Docker\pki`.

**I added** `127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal` to hosts file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

**I disabled antivirus when I tried to install docker desktop.**

**I uninstalled docker desktop and installed again.**

this logs is from `C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\service.txt`:

```
Version: 3.3.3 (64133)
Sha1: 68eba96de8051dcb12cf43b3a6955f1ee7156b4b
Started on: 2021/06/08 15:34:54.701
Resources: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
Edition: Enterprise
Id: 2009
Build: 19042
BuildLabName: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
File: C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\service.txt
CommandLine: "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\com.docker.service"
You can send feedback, including this log file, at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues
[15:34:54.808][DockerService     ][Info   ] Starting service
[15:35:27.136][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [ea10531c] <Server start> GET http://localhost/version
[15:35:27.232][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [ea10531c] <Server end> GET http://localhost/version -> 200 OK (took 94ms)
[15:35:27.390][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [07e807dc] <Server start> GET http://localhost/hyperv/vhdx-size?path=C:%5CProgramData%5CDockerDesktop%5Cvm-data%5CDockerDesktop.vhdx
[15:35:27.448][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [07e807dc] <Server end> GET http://localhost/hyperv/vhdx-size?path=C:%5CProgramData%5CDockerDesktop%5Cvm-data%5CDockerDesktop.vhdx -> 200 OK (took 58ms)
[15:35:27.465][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [e3a26e19] <Server start> POST http://localhost/migrate/app
[15:35:27.467][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [e3a26e19] <Server end> POST http://localhost/migrate/app -> 204 NoContent (took 2ms)
[15:35:28.659][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [715f350a] <Server start> POST http://localhost/versionpack/enable
[15:35:28.770][VersionPackConfigLoader][Info   ] Version pack folder not found (C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-packs), returning empty config.
[15:35:28.770][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [715f350a] <Server end> POST http://localhost/versionpack/enable -> 204 NoContent (took 110ms)
[15:35:28.810][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [06dbf81e] <Server start> POST http://localhost/dns/refresh-hosts
[15:35:29.187][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [06dbf81e] <Server end> POST http://localhost/dns/refresh-hosts -> 204 NoContent (took 376ms)
[08:49:30.059][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [70da1224] <Server start> GET http://localhost/version
[08:49:30.062][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [70da1224] <Server end> GET http://localhost/version -> 200 OK (took 1ms)
[08:49:30.081][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [089f57f7] <Server start> GET http://localhost/hyperv/vhdx-size?path=C:%5CProgramData%5CDockerDesktop%5Cvm-data%5CDockerDesktop.vhdx
[08:49:30.113][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [089f57f7] <Server end> GET http://localhost/hyperv/vhdx-size?path=C:%5CProgramData%5CDockerDesktop%5Cvm-data%5CDockerDesktop.vhdx -> 200 OK (took 31ms)
[08:49:30.127][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [027a85d8] <Server start> POST http://localhost/migrate/app
[08:49:30.128][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [027a85d8] <Server end> POST http://localhost/migrate/app -> 204 NoContent (took 0ms)
[08:49:44.320][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [83288ced] <Server start> POST http://localhost/versionpack/enable
[08:49:44.325][VersionPackConfigLoader][Info   ] Version pack folder not found (C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-packs), returning empty config.
[08:49:44.325][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [83288ced] <Server end> POST http://localhost/versionpack/enable -> 204 NoContent (took 5ms)
[08:49:45.695][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [64bd07d5] <Server start> POST http://localhost/dns/refresh-hosts
[08:49:45.869][LoggingMessageHandler][Info   ] [64bd07d5] <Server end> POST http://localhost/dns/refresh-hosts -> 204 NoContent (took 173ms)
```

[image]

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hello @mohammad nowresideh, do you have enabled virtualization in BIOS? Maybe you find the solution by reading [this topic](https://gitmemory.com/issue/docker/for-win/6714/628635566)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15407542/miko%c5%82aj-g%c5%82odziak Thanks, I will check later

Comment: do you have any progress?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15407542/miko%c5%82aj-g%c5%82odziak Yes, i solved the problem with another solution, thank you.

Comment: please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15407542/miko%c5%82aj-g%c5%82odziak Sure.